# How to load custom Fonts in an Expo app using React Navigation and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo, react-navigation

I just can not load custom fonts in an existing app using Expo, React Natvigation. I have an app that has Navigations set up in a core.js file as

```
    import React from "react";
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import LoginScreen from "./login.js";
import RegisterScreen from "./register.js";
//import Home from "./home.js";
import PostAJobPage from "./secondTab.js";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons"
import store from "./store";
import SplashScreen from "./splashscreen";
import Home from "./homeStack.js";
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import SearchAJobStack from "./jobsearchstack.js";


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const Tabs = () => {
  return(
    //<NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName = "home"
        screenOptions = {({route}) => ({
          tabBarIcon : ({focused,color, size}) => {
            let iconName;
            if(route.name == "home") {
              iconName = "ios-home"
              return <Ionicons name = {iconName} color = {color} size = {size}/>
            }
            else if(route.name == "postJob")
            {
              //iconName = "md-settings"
              iconName = "briefcase"
              return <Entypo name = {iconName} color = {color} size = {size}/>
            }
            else if (route.name == "searchJob")
            {
              iconName = "briefcase-search"
              return <MaterialCommunityIcons name = {iconName} size={size} color= {color} />
            }

            //return <Ionicons name = {iconName} color = {color} size = {size}/>
          }
        })}
        tabBarOptions = {{
          style : {
            height : 50
          },
          showLabel : false,
          activeTintColor : "gold"
        }

        }>
        <Tab.Screen name="home" component ={Home}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="postJob" component ={PostAJobPage}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="searchJob" component ={SearchAJobStack}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    //</NavigationContainer>
  )
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function Stacks() {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName = "loadingPage">
        <Stack.Screen
          name = "loadingPage"
          component = {SplashScreen}
          options = {{
            headerShown : false
          }}/>

        <Stack.Screen
          name ="Main"
          component = {Tabs}
          options = {{
            headerShown : false,
          }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name= "login"
          component = {LoginScreen}
          options = {{
            title : "Login",
            headerTitleAlign : "left"
          }}/>

        <Stack.Screen name= "register"
          component = {RegisterScreen}
          options = {{
            title : "Register",
            headerTitleAlign : "left",
          }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default class core extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <Stacks/>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor : "#fff",
    alignItems : "center",
    justifyContent : "center",
  }
})
```

I am importing this stacks in my App.js and have added the code to add custom fonts according to the Docs in Expo but if I change `fontFamily: Pacifico` to any of the screens it doesnot work

My app.js file is

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Core from "./core.js";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import store from "./store.js";
import * as Font from "expo-font";

const customFonts = {
  dancingScript : require("./assets/fonts/DancingScript-Regular.ttf"),
  Pacifico : require("./assets/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf"),
  Inter : require("./assets/fonts/Inter-VariableFont.ttf"),
}


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontsLoaded : false,
  }
  async _loadFontsAsync() {
    await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
    this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadFontsAsync();
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.fontsLoaded)
    {
      return (
        <Provider store = {store}>
          
          <Core/>

        </Provider>
      );
    }
    else {
      return(
        <View style= {styles.container}>
          <Image source = {require("./ajax-loader.gif")}/>
        </View>
      )
    }

  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    //fontFamily : "dancingScript",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally feel this is a better way to load custom fonts. I use this method in all my projects. To `loadFonts` create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located

Then, Install `expo-app-loading` & `expo-font`

Then inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Inside `useFonts.js` write like this

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default useFonts = async () => {
   await Font.loadAsync({
      "Pacifico" : require("./assets/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf"),
      // All other fonts here
    });
};
```

Now in your `App.js` write like this

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return <View styles={styles.container}>{/* Code Here */}</View>;
}
```

**Note: The above solution was for `Function` components.**

For **`Class Component`**, you can do something like this

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/class-component-custom-fonts)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontsLoaded: false,
  };

  async _loadFontsAsync() {
    await useFonts();
    this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadFontsAsync();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.fontsLoaded) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Fonts Loaded</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Helvetica' }}>Helvetica Text</Text>
          <Text>Normal Text</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://landerapp.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/1_FFP1bisztXseQFbZ-WQedw-1.png',
            }}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    //fontFamily : "dancingScript",
  },
});
```

Comment: correction it worked, I was changing the fontfamily of some Text that already had fontWeight : "bold", it was not letting it change, removing fontweight solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can load your fonts in an expo app write the code in the entry point of your app which is mainly App.js

```
  import { useFonts } from "expo-font"; 

   const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        // Axiforma: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Black.ttf"),
        // BlackItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-BlackItalic.ttf"),
        Bold: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Bold.ttf"),
        // BoldItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-BoldItalic.ttf"),
        // Book: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Book.ttf"),
        // BookItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-BookItalic.ttf"),
        ExtraBold: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-ExtraBold.ttf"),
        // ExtraBoldItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf"),
        // Heavy: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Heavy.ttf"),
        // HeavyItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-HeavyItalic.ttf"),
        // Italic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Italic.ttf"),
        Light: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Light.ttf"),
        // LightItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-LightItalic.ttf"),
        Medium: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Medium.ttf"),
        // MediumItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-MediumItalic.ttf"),
        Regular: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Regular.ttf"),
        SemiBold: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-SemiBold.ttf"),
        // SemiBoldItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-SemiBoldItalic.ttf"),
        Thin: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-Thin.ttf"),
        // ThinItalic: require("./assets/fonts/Axiforma-ThinItalic.ttf"),
      });
      if (!fontsLoaded) return <AppLoading />;
```

Comment: This is not helping, still cant seem to get them change on any of the screens

Answer (score 0):

Use *@expo-google-fonts*

Go to the project root from the terminal and type to install the font that wish, example:

```
expo install @expo-google-fonts/ubuntu
```

The explo cli will install all ubuntu fonts as a node module, look inside the path ./node_modules/@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu, all fonts are there.

Now, import the hook and the font styles that you wish from this font family, like this:

```
import { useFonts, Ubuntu_400Regular, Ubuntu_500Medium, Ubuntu_700Bold } from '@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu';
```

Then, load them inside your app using the hook:

```
let [fontsReady,fontsError] = useFonts({Ubuntu_400Regular, Ubuntu_500Medium, Ubuntu_700Bold});
```

**fontsReady** will be true when the fonts are ready to use and the **fontsError** will has the error reason if the app could not load the fonts.

To wait the fonts be ready, use *expo-app-loading* module and do something like this:

```
if (!fontsReady) return <AppLoading/>;
```

To choose the fonts that you wish to install on your project, visit https://directory.vercel.app/ , this will show all Google fonts and the import cmd in an easy way. Do not forget to include the useFonts hook.