# expo-font not showing custom font

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm having trouble with trying to load custom fonts into my Expo React-native App.

Here is my code.

App.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native-paper';

const App = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={LoadFonts}
          onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
          onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
        />
      );
    }

      return (
          <Text style={{fontFamily: 'ProximaNova-Regular'}}>Some Text</Text>
      );
}
```

hooks/useFonts.js

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const useFonts = async() => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'ProximaNova-Regular': require('../assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf'),
  });
};

export default useFonts;
```

The problem is Expo is not displaying my custom font and just displaying the default font even when I specifiy the font like

```
fontFamily: 'ProximaNova-Regular'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Arnav

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981828/how-to-load-custom-fonts-in-an-expo-app-using-react-navigation-and-redux/68982349#68982349) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569844/react-native-expo-custom-fonts-not-loading-with-font-loadasync/68570172#68570172) one too. Upvote it if it solves your problem.

Comment: Theres alot of out of the box fonts from expo-google-fonts maybe check this out (https://github.com/expo/google-fonts) it's different than expo-fonts